# Arduino YUN - complex JSON response

Tags: json, rest, arduino-yun

I am using Bridge library on my Arduino YUN to create `REST` web service. Is there any way to create complex JSON response?

Comment: Look at aJSON on github import it in and you can build a complex structure using arrays and objects just like most programming languages. https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson

Comment: Instead of trying to hack this together through the Arduino IDE - which will be painful - why don't you just get the data over to the Linux side of things and use Ruby/PHP/node.js to make the JSON and serve it through Apache or some such?